# Identify and remove duplicate elements based on multiple attributes in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to perform an xslt transformation such that duplicate elements are filtered based on multiple attributes. 
Input XML :

```
<rootNode>
<node id="N10102017004" bomHeader="true">
    <request>
       <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017004">
    <request>
        <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017004">
    <request>
        <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017056" bomHeader="true">
    <request>
       <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017056">
    <request>
         <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017056">
    <request>
        <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017089">
    <request>
        <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017090">
    <request>
         <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017090">
    <request>
        <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
```

What I want is when node element has id and bomHeader attribute , then based on id the duplicate element needs to be removed. If bomHeader attribute is not there then the duplicate id elements need not be deleted.

My XSL returns :

```
<rootNode>
<node id="N10102017004" bomHeader="true">
    <request>
       <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017004">
    <request>
        <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>

<node id="N10102017056" bomHeader="true">
    <request>
       <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017056">
    <request>
         <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>

<node id="N10102017089">
    <request>
        <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017090">
    <request>
         <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
```

Expected OUTPUT XML :

```
<rootNode>
<node id="N10102017004" bomHeader="true">
    <request>
       <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>

<node id="N10102017056" bomHeader="true">
    <request>
       <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>

<node id="N10102017089">
    <request>
        <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017090">
    <request>
         <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
<node id="N10102017090">
    <request>
        <someText>aaa</someText>
    </request>
</node>
```

Comment: Can you share the XSL code that you have written so far?

Comment: `<xsl:key name="kNode" match="fulfillmentLineItem" use="concat(@id,'|', @bomHeader)"/> 
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fulfillmentLineItem[generate-id() = 
        generate-id(key('kNode',concat(@id,'|', @bomHeader))[1])]">  <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Drop other <NodeE> elements -->
    <xsl:template match="fulfillmentLineItem"/>`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XSLT you have tried, as it is hard to read code in comments. Also, the XSLT is matching `fulfillmentLineItem` but there are no elements of that name in your XML. Thank you.